# Angular Shopping Cart Fails To Clear Items

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs

Hello I'm trying trying to empty my shopping cart using an api. I have a check out page(items based on shopping cart) where user chooses method of payment, after a transaction is successful I want to empty the shopping cart. I'm able to load cart, add an item  to the cart as well as delete an item from the cart, but it is all based on an id.

I want to empty everything in the cart (What I doing is getting the items and then I try to empty the array). As I mentioned checkout is based on what is in the shopping cart but I can not figure out why I can't empty the cart no matter what I try I continue to get the cart items. Can someone please point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong. It would be greatly appreciated. Code snippet below.

Cart Model

```
import { Product } from './product';

export class CartItem {
    id: number;
    productId: number;
    productName: string;
    qty: number;
    price: number;
    size:string;
    imageUrl:string;

    constructor(id:number, size:string,  product:Product, qty= 1) {

        this.id = id;
        this.productId = product.id;
        this.price = product.price;
        this.size = size;
        this.productName = product.name;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.imageUrl = product.imageUrl;
         
        
    }

   
}
```

Cart Component

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

 
  @Input() product: CartItem;
  @Input() cartItem: CartItem;
  
  cartUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/cart';

   cartItems = [

   ];
   
   constructor(private msg: MessengerService, private 
   cartService:CartService, private productService: 
   ProductService, private formBuilder:FormBuilder, private 
   _data:AppserviceService) { }
 
  
 

  ngOnInit(): void {

     this.handleSubscription();
     this.loadCartItems();

  }

  handleSubscription(){

    this.msg.getMsg().subscribe((product: Product) => {   
     this.loadCartItems();
     
    })

   }


   loadCartItems(){

     this.cartService.getCartItems().subscribe((items: CartItem[]) 
     => {
     this.cartItems = items;
     
    })
   }



 handleClearCart(){
  alert("here at cart")
    this.cartService.clearCart().subscribe((items: CartItem[]) =>{  
     this.cartItems = items;
      alert("Does It Get Here");
       console.log("Trying to Empty Cart From Cart");

 })

}
      

 }
```

cartService

```
export class CartService {

  id: number;
  
  product: any;
  /*cartItems = [

  ];*/

  items: CartItem[] = [];
    
  cartUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/cart';
  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    
 }

/*To do  mapping the obtained results out to card items props pipe and mapp functions will be used.
 The observable returneded by carUrl is the source is going to pipe through the map projection and get results of CartItem*/

   getCartItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
     return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(cartUrl).pipe(

      map((result: any[]) => {
        let cartItems: CartItem[] =[];
        

     for(let item of result) {
            
       cartItems.push( new CartItem(item.id, item.size, item.product, 
       item.imageUrl ));
           
          
       }
         
        return cartItems;
        
       })
     );

        
   }
 
  

   addProductToCart(product:Product):Observable<any>{
     return this.http.post(cartUrl, {product});
   }

   

   RemoveProductFromCart(id:number):Observable<void>{
      return this.http.delete<CartItem[]>(`${this.cartUrl}/${id}`)
     .pipe(catchError(_err => of (null))
      
     );
    }

  
   clearCart():  Observable<CartItem[]> {
    return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(cartUrl).pipe(
     map((result: any[]) => {
      // let cartItems: CartItem[] =[];
      //for(let item of result) {   
           //cartItems = []
       
         this.items=[]

          console.log("Should Empty Cart");
      
            return this.items;
       
      })
    );

       
  }
     


}
```

Comment: there is something not very clears. Where do you store the items of the cart, in `CartService ` or `CartComponent`? I see two arrays, this confuses me.
also what exactly is not working? Why can't you just empty the array? and what's the problem? In the UI? Do you have an error?

Comment: also, you are calling `return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(cartUrl).pipe(` this is just a get request... seems pointless. You are not emprying the cart in the Backend but anly in the frontend... probably this is the problem